# Wanting to Push to UIViewContoller, from UIViewController via openURL and custom URL navigation

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview, uitextview, uiapplication

I'm currently working on an application that requires a new view to be pushed to when the user clicks on a URL (This new view contains a UIWebView with browser functions). I've got this working perfectly from UIWebViews within the application, I'm just wanting to get it to work from a UITextView too.

At the moment I'm detecting that a url is being clicked on, and cancelling Safari being opened up by sub-classing UIApplication as below:

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if  ([self handleOpenURL:url])
        return YES;
    else
        return [super openURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", request.URL]);

    return YES;
}
```

Which is then logging the URL I want to visit. The main issues is that I then want to push to a new UIViewController. Usually I would use this method (which works perfectly with the UIWebViews, as I'm implementing it on the UIViewContoller I'm wanting to push from):

```
- (void)openWebViewWithURL:(NSURLRequest *)request fromView:(UIViewController *)view withTitle:(NSString *)title
```

Is there any way that I can either detect the current view that has the UITextField in it (therefore passing through the current view to my method), or a way of overriding the `- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url` call from within the UIViewController I'm currently using?

Comment: We're you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Check the UITextField's `superView` property.